# can @Input and @output used to call each other methods with just importing but not in parent child

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a scenario where a component is imported into another component and `@input` is being used to send a filename to another component. Here it is not parent-child relation, instead it is just a import call into another component.

component 1 -

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbDateStruct, NgbModalOptions, ModalDismissReasons, NgbTabChangeEvent, NgbTypeahead } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ReviewComponent } from './loto.reviewdoc.component';export

class LotoReviewTabComponent implements OnInit {
.
.
.
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private LotoService: LotoService) {

.
.
.
```

A filename is being passed to `ReviewComponent`  using `@input` -

```
    const reviewModal = this.modalService.open(ReviewComponent, ngbModalOptions);
    reviewModal.componentInstance.fileName = fileName;
```

Now, my requirement is to call a method of `LotoReviewTabComponent`  inside a method of  `ReviewComponent`

Here there is no child-parent thing. `ReviewComponent`  is just imported into `LotoReviewTabComponent` . How can this be achieved?.

Comment: Are you trying to share data between sibling components under the parent component?

Comment: @ShankarGaneshJayaraman No, there is no parent component here. Component 1 has imported component 2. A method in component 2 should call a method is component 1. Is that possible?.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with `@ViewChild` decorator. Check her - https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/advanced-components/access_child_components